# Automapper , Linq and Localizaton

Tags: c#, linq, localization, automapper

Recently I have been playing with `AutoMapper` as a tool to populate our `DTOs`.
The cool thing about AutoMapper is its `Project().To()` that let us map a `Queryable` so that we can select the fields that we want according to our map.

But here we have another scenario too.We want to be able to translate some of the values of an entity into other representation.

Suppose that we have a string field that its value in DB is 'Apparatment' and we want to translate it to another language while we are selecting our `DTOs`.

I think that if we want to write this in SQL it will be something like this :

```
SELECT CASE BuidlingType WHEN 'Appartment' THEN 'apparatment  in another langaure' WHEN 'Flat' THEN 'flat in another languate' END AS BuildingType FROM buildings
```

I know that we can define value resolvers in AutoMapper. The question I would like to ask is ,can we use these resolvers in a Project().To() scenario ? If the answer is yes then how we should use them (to return an expression instead of a value) and if not , is there any other alternative approach to be able to translate a DTO on the fly ?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't use resolvers in LINQ projections.

I guess I'm a little confused - those translations look a little difficult in the SQL you have. Are your translations stored in a database, or do you hard code them in your SQL?

Typically my localized labels are stored either in resource files or specialized tables. If they're in tables, I don't necessarily returned translated data labels with data. I have two queries and the translation query is almost certainly cached.

I would start with "What LINQ do I build to make the correct SQL" and then I can help with "how can I configure AutoMapper to build this LINQ?"

Comment: May I ask what do you mean by translation query ? and how we should use a translation query ? Those translations that you see are hard coded in our DTOs mappers.

Comment: Translation query usually being "grab all the resource keys, locales and translations once per AppDomain". What does your translation in your DTOs today look like?

Comment: What if we ignore the localisation part of the question and instead think we had something like a string being read from the DB being translated into one of several enum values/flags.  Would that frame the question better? (as someone about to use AutoMapper in more areas of our project I'm genuinely curious about how to solve such use cases to have in my toolbelt)   :)

Comment: Yeah I guess I wouldn't solve this at the mapping layer. Just like I wouldn't solve currency localization at the DB, that's done at the boundaries.